# UIView subviews don't responde to delegates

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:nil] ;
self.myView = myViewController.view;
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

This code loads view from myView.nib (I have corresponding view controller m and h files of course). myView view has `UITextField` and other controls. So far so good - I can see all my controls on the screen.

The problem however is that even though I set a delegate for `UITextField` to be File's Owner (which is myView) and I implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in myView.m, delegate methods are never fired!

This does NOT happen if I add `UITextField` to the original view (created by the XCode as default template). Why is this happening?

The reason I need to useSubview because in actual code will layer view to the `UIScrollView` so I can pan and zoom.

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

My first question to your question is, "is there a reason to use UIViewController to load your NIB file?".

It appears that you're "throwing away" the UIViewController and merely using it for its ability to load a NIB file.  I'd stop that first, as that may help you debug this issue.  Use:

```
self.myView = (UIView*)[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"myView"];
```

The second part I'd question is that you say "File's Owner" -- because you're using a separate UIViewController, you may have it set to call back to your UIViewController, not the code that you mean to callback to.  Maybe you could tell us a little about the setup of the XIB file?